# There is a form to save the projects stored of mlflow docker image and don't lose the data?

Tags: python, docker, mlflow, artifact

I am running a mlflow docker image with this configuration:

```bash
docker run --restart always -itd --name mlflow -p 5000:5000 -v ~/mlflow:/mlflow ghcr.io/mlflow/mlflow mlflow server -h 0.0.0.0
```

The problem is that each time I delete the docker image, all the data stored in there as experiments and models are deleted. `-v` parameter doesn't help, as it just saves the data that I create within a shell inside the docker image, but I want to save the data that is processed in mlflow UI.

So, is there any way to avoid losing the data stored in mlflow UI?

Docker image of this service: https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/docker.html

Answer (score 0):

In the case of the image `ghcr.io/mlflow/mlflow:v2.11.1`, MLflow generates data at two locations: `/mlruns` and `/mlartifacts` ([source](https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/tracking/artifacts-stores.html)).

The following command allows us to launch the MLflow container while persisting the models and other MLflow data in our local directory `/home/mlflow`:

```
docker run -it --name mlflow -p 5000:5000 -v /home/mlflow/mlruns:/mlruns -v /home/mlflow/mlartifacts:/mlartifacts ghcr.io/mlflow/mlflow:v2.11.1 mlflow ui --host 0.0.0.0
```